# Raw video dump to file using no encoding with usb webcam

Tags: usb, video, webcam, ffmpeg

I would like to dump raw video (and hardware encoded mjpeg) to be dumped into a file using usb webcam.

On following command,

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext

ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
        Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
        Name        : MJPEG
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

I would like to choose one of the profile listed here without any encoding. Please help how to achieve this. I tried with

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mjpeg
```

But I get JPEG image with 640x480. Please help

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to change the input_format to "yuyv422".

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -output.avi
```

or

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -output.mpg
```